How to Resolve "Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches" Error When Rebasing in Git?
I encountered an error while trying to rebase my GitHub project
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.

fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.

2024-07-19 17:33:01.928 [info] > git config --get commit.template [39ms]
2024-07-19 17:33:01.932 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) --ignore-case refs/heads/soleimani refs/remotes/soleimani [40ms]
2024-07-19 17:33:01.985 [info] > git status -z -uall [51ms]

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22hint%3A+You+have+divergent+branches+and+need+to+specify+how+to+reconcile+them%22

try this:
git config pull.rebase true
